# Implementing jquery.noconflict() in MVC4 with TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

I have an MVC 4 application which uses the TinyMCE HTML Editor and Jquery Modal Popups along with the Bootstrap Nav-bar. I'm getting conflict issues between TinyMCE and Jquery which breaks the Navbar on pages including TinyMCE. I've tried to resolve these issues by changing the order of script loading plus initializing TinyMCE before Jquery but its not solving the issue.

I wondered how I would use Jquery.Noconflict() to avoid this issue?

Currently in my _Layout.cshtml page I have the code for the Modal Popup, and then an EditorTemplate.cshtml file for TinyMCE which is then loaded through the UIHint in my model, should I use jquery.noconflict(); in these two script instances?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you can use $j instead of $ in your jquery code.

[Jquery No conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Managed to get this working but unfortunately not solved the overall issue!